# How do I link two HTML pages with a button?

Tags: html, button

I've got two HTML pages, with one being an opening page for an application and the second being a login page. I have a button on the opening page and I want to be able to click on it and have it take me to the login page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

This will add a button and link it to the login page:

```
<a href="path_to_login_page">
  <button>Take me to the login page</button>
</a>
```

Change `path_to_login_page` & `Take me to the login page` to customize the button. If you already have a customized button and want to use it:

```
<a href="path_to_login_page">
  'Place your button here'
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would just change the button to a standard anchor. You could still style the link to make it look like a button.

```
<a href="index.html">Go home</a>
```

If the element really must remain a button, you could do this:

```
<button onclick="location.href='index.html'>Go home</button>
```

It's not exactly best practice, though.

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS THE SHORTEST AND THE FASTEST WAY TO DO IT:

```
<a href="login-page.html">
<button> Login Page</button>
</a>
```

Run and Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/2zov6q2v/14/